# Complex-conjugate poles from transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, math

This comes from Sedra's *Microelectronic Circuits*, example 17.1.

If I have a transfer function with a pole \$p_1 = \omega_0(-0.1736 + j0.9848)\$.

The example talks about "combining \$p_1\$ with its complex conjugate", becoming \$s^2+0.3472s + \omega_0^2\$.

By trial and error I found that this "combining with its complex-conjugate" assumes an expression \$s^2 + (p_1 + \overline{p_1})s + p_1 \overline{p_1}\$. But I don't get what this combination means exactly and why it needs to happen here.

Comment: Please show the transfer function.

Comment: This question should not be closed. There is more than sufficient detail and clarity.

Comment: @RussellH It's an academic question and those require an attempt at a solution.

Comment: @VoltageSpike: From my point of view, the attempt was made. A solution was found. But the meaning of the so;ution was not clear. The question was about understanding the solution not providing one..:)

Comment: @RussellH The OP mentions "by trial and error" but they did not post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For realizable systems, complex poles always occur in pairs. For example, a second order transfer function can be written:
$$
G(s)=\frac{N(s)}{s^2+a_1s+a_0}
$$
Or factored into poles as:
$$
G(s)=\frac{N(s)}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)}
$$

If \$p_1\$ is complex then so must \$p_2\$ be the complex  conjugate of \$p_1\$.

If a pole is complex, then its conjugate must exist, so the denominitor of the transfer function can be found as is shown in the OP. That's all this means.

For higher order systems, each pair of complex poles will reveal a quadratic factor in the denominator.

Comment: Brilliant. This was exactly the "click" I was looking for expressed in simple terms. Thank you very much!